# Fluent UI 9 TextArea input field with useForm hook wher error happen it's loose my focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, fluent-ui

I loose the focus when error happen the in textArea Component, and when i menualy all the foucs using ref.focus method it's ignore the previous type value and it's my new charector start in 0th position,

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  makeStyles,
  shorthands,
  useId,
  Input,
  Label,
  Field,
  Textarea,
} from "@fluentui/react-components";
import {
  Controller,
  ControllerFieldState,
  ControllerRenderProps,
  FieldValues,
  UseFormStateReturn,
  useFormContext,
} from "react-hook-form";

interface inputField {
  name: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  label?: string;
  icon?: React.ReactNode;
  isRequired?: boolean;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    ...shorthands.gap("20px"),
    // Prevent the example from taking the full width of the page (optional)
    maxWidth: "900px",
    width: "100%",
    // Stack the label above the field (with 2px gap per the design system)
    "> div": {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      ...shorthands.gap("3px"),
    },
  },
});

export const TextAreaField = (props: inputField) => {
  const styles = useStyles();

  const { control, formState, register } = useFormContext();
  const err = formState.errors[props.name]?.message as string | null;

  console.log(formState);

  const inputId = useId("TextArea");

  return (
    <Controller
      key={"TextArea"}
      control={control}
      name={props.name}
      defaultValue={formState.defaultValues}
      render={function ({
        field,
        fieldState,
        formState,
      }: {
        field: ControllerRenderProps<FieldValues, string>;
        fieldState: ControllerFieldState;
        formState: UseFormStateReturn<FieldValues>;
      }): React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
        return (
          <div key="This is Text Area" className={styles.root}>
            <div key="InnerTable">
              <Label
                className={props.isRequired ? "red-star" : ""}
                style={{ fontWeight: "bold", letterSpacing: "0.3px" }}
                htmlFor={props.name}
              >
                {props.label}
              </Label>
              <Field
                key={"Error"}
                validationMessage={
                  formState.errors[props.name]?.message as string
                }
              >
                <Textarea
                  key="NoRender"
                  size="medium"
                  id={inputId}
                  placeholder={props.placeholder}
                  {...field}
                  // contentBefore={props.icon}
                  // onChange={(e, d) => {
                  //   field.onChange(d.value);
                  // }}

                  ref={(inputRef) => {
                    if (inputRef && formState.name === props.name) {
                      inputRef.focus();
                      inputRef.autofocus = true;
                    }
                  }}
                />
              </Field>
              {/* <ErrorComponent errorMessage={props.errorMessage} /> */}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }}
    ></Controller>
  );
};

export default React.memo(TextAreaField);
```

my TextArea component

```
const AddAndUpdateAddressWidgets: FormField[] = [
  {
    componentType: "TextField",
    order: 2,
    props: {
      errorMessage: "",
      name: "address_name",
      label: "address_name",
      options: [],
      placeholder: "",
      disabled: false,
      width: "",
    },
  },
  {
    componentType: "TextField",
    order: 3,
    props: {
      errorMessage: "",
      name: "pin_code",
      label: "Pincode",
      options: [],
      placeholder: "",
      disabled: false,
      width: "",
    },
  },
  {
    componentType: "TextField",
    order: 4,
    props: {
      errorMessage: "",
      name: "district_name",
      label: "District",
      options: [],
      placeholder: "",
      disabled: false,
      width: "",
    },
  },

  {
    componentType: "TextAreaField",
    order: 5,
    props: {
      errorMessage: "",
      name: "address_line_1",
      label: "Address Line 1",
      options: [],
      placeholder: "",
      disabled: false,
      width: "",
    },
  },
  {
    componentType: "TextAreaField",
    order: 6,
    props: {
      errorMessage: "",
      name: "address_line_2",
      label: "Address Line 2",
      options: [],
      placeholder: "",
      disabled: false,
      width: "",
    },
  },
  {
    componentType: "TextAreaField",
    order: 7,
    props: {
      errorMessage: "",
      name: "office_remarks",
      label: "office_remarks",
      options: [],
      placeholder: "",
      disabled: false,
      width: "",
    },
  },
];

export default AddAndUpdateAddressWidgets;
```

i use my component in loop with state.

```
          {sortedAddAndUpdateWidgets.map(
              (
                field: { componentType: string | number; props: any },
                index: any
              ) => {
                const Component = React.memo(
                  componentRegistry[field.componentType]
                );
                return (
                  <Component
                    key={index}
                    {...field.props}
                    //   errorMessage={
                    //     addAndUpdateErrors[field.props.name]?.message || ""
                    //   }
                  />
                );
              }
            )}
```

i use like this

this is the state, which i use to render the component,

so i use fluent UI 9 TextArea and input,

Input element is work fine but TextArea is now work how i fix

i try to type a value in text area but it's not work when validation error happen, it's lose the control, and when i type any value error is gone and my component is rerender, it's ignore previous value, and new value appere in 0th position